# What negative effects can Esuna cure?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-12

Final Fantasy 12 contains a lovely spell called Esuna(ga), which clears negative status effects from a character in your party. Memory serving, the original game's Esuna cleared almost everything; Blind, Poison, Sap, Doom, Oil, etc.

This does not appear to be the case with The Zodiac Age. When going through the Stillshrine of Miriam, my entire party became afflicted with Oil, but Esuna would not clear it.

Is Esuna tied to the licenses of "Remedies remove more negative effects", or has its effectiveness been changed for TZA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [White Magicks](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/White_Magicks_(Final_Fantasy_XII)) page, the Esuna(ga) does not remove the following negative statuses.

(emphasis my own)

> Esuna: Effect: Removes negative statuses from one target. **Does not remove Oil, Critical HP, X-Zone, KO, Stone, Stop, Doom, Disease, or Slow.**
>
> Esunaga: Effect: Removes negative statuses from all targets in range. **Does not remove Oil, Critical HP, X-Zone, KO, Stone, Stop, Doom, Disease, or Slow.**

I cannot recall if this functioned the same before, but seeing there are no categories labeled as FFXII/Zodiac, it would appear these white magicks also functioned the same in the original version

Comment: huh, I guess I've remembered incorrectly. That kind of sucks that there isn't a spell to remove Oil!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yeah, it does. I remember now having to stockpile on Handkerchiefs because Esuna didn't remove it